# mysql SQL statement doesn't work C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have been trying to make this code block work, but I can't seem to find the error in it. It doesn't return the value that I am looking for. I would try to run the SQL statement in workbench and it returns my desired number of rows(which is 3).

```
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(GlobalValues.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText =
                        @"
                            SELECT strDetPremID, strPremiseName
                                    FROM tbldetailprem 
                                    INNER JOIN tblpremise ON strDetPremID = strPremiseID
                                    WHERE strDetPremContID = @id;
                            ;
                            "
                        ;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        this.Clear();
                        da.Fill(this);
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString() + " - " + ex.Number);
        }
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong with this code

Comment: Your running a select statement, and calling for 2 values (strDetPremID and strPremiseName) and you're expecting a int back? How is that statement only returning `3`? You're also not affecting any rows by selecting.

Comment: What kind of application is this?  Typically what I do is execute a datareader, then assign the variable based on the datareader's property.  Your SQL is a `SELECT` statement, so why are you doing `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: @kalamazoowho - It appears to be an instance of `MySqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: A select statement is a query, but you use `ExecuteNonQuery`.  Also it's not clear what part of that query should give you a result of only 3.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to count the number of rows, use the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbldetailprem 
INNER JOIN tblpremise ON strDetPremID = strPremiseID
WHERE strDetPremContID = @id;
```

Then use the `ExecuteScalar()` method on the command object to get the value of `COUNT(*)`.
The `ExecuteNonQuery()` is used for adding, updating and deleting records, not for selecting them.

More information can be found here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html

Answer (score 0):

This may serve more as a comment but I lack the rep to comment.

It's not exactly clear, to me, in the code where the issue may be coming from so my assumption is that there's a bug that's not being caught as a `MySQLException`.

Have you tried removing the try/catch statement in order to catch any bugs that would prevent `affectedRows` being updated?

Also, I'm not sure if it's causing a SyntaxError or not but it seems you have an extra semicolon in `cmd.CommandText`... I think.